Does all electrical energy in circuits convert to heat?
Electric power is defined as "the rate of transfer of electrical energy within a circuit" as per wiki. Its formula is given as $P=VI$.  But then heat dissipated by current in a circuit is also defined by $VI$.
Doesn't it mean all electrical energy going through the circuit per second becomes heat energy? If so, then why such a current is able to light a bulb if assume a bulb is now connected to the circuit, because the current would not have any energy left after heat dissipation to change to light energy, or why such current is able to rotate a fan creating kinetic energy?

In a non-trivial circuit there are multiple elements with separate voltages and currents, so there isn't one $V$ and one $I$ per circuit.


But then heat dissipated by current in a circuit is also defined by VI

This isn't strictly correct. It is appropriate for resistors and transistors, but not necessarily for other devices designed to convert electrical energy to other forms.
In an LED, a portion of the energy is converted to light.
In a motor, a portion of the energy is converted to mechanical work.

why such a current is able to light a bulb if assume a bulb is now connected to the circuit,

Incandescent light bulbs are so inefficient (maybe 2-3% efficient) in converting electrical energy to light that it is a reasonable approximation to say that all of their energy is converted to heat. The light output is small enough to be rounding error in an everyday (as opposed to extremely precise) power conversion calcuation.

No, the power used by all circuit elements is $P = IV$ but not all of that power goes into heat for every kind of circuit element.
For example, in an ideal capacitor the power goes into energy for creating electric fields. In an inductor the power goes into energy for creating magnetic fields.
A fan motor is pretty much an inductor. The power goes into turning the inductor coils of wire in the motor into electromagnets. That creates magnetic potential energy which then turns into kinetic energy for the fan blades. The air resistance and friction on the fan try to slow down the blades, and so the circuit has to keep providing power to the inductors to keep the fan going.
